# Can I take an element from the blockingQueue and add that element to a Map?

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I am wondering is there a way to use the take() function for a blockingqueue and add each element i am taking and add it to a map ? Or would I have to add to map while I am adding to the queue?

What i am doing is parsing input text into ngrams and then adding them to a blockingQueue, once the blockingQueue has all the elements , i want to `take()` from the queue and add them to a map, which I have in another class.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class FileParser implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<Task> queue;
    private String fileName;
    private int k;
    private Database dbFile = null;

    public FileParser(BlockingQueue<Task> queue,String fileName, int k) {
        this.queue=queue;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.k = k;
    }


    public void setDbFile(Database dbFile) {
        this.dbFile = dbFile;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            file();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void file() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                nGram(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    private void nGram(String j) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i <= j.length() - k; i++) {
            CharSequence ngrams = j.substring(i, i + k);
            Task t=new Task(ngrams);
            queue.put(t);
            System.out.println("Adding "+t);
        }
    }

}
```

```
//Responsible for removing from the queue

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Task> queue;
    private volatile boolean keepRunning = true;
    private Database dbFile = null;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Task> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (keepRunning) {
            try {
                Task t = (queue.take());
                if (t instanceof Poison) {
                    keepRunning = false;
                    System.out.println("Queue poisoned->" + t);
                }

                System.out.println("Removing " + t);
//Error here:
                //dbFile.addFile(t);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
** Output **
Adding  N-gram [ ye]
Removing  N-gram [ He]
Adding  N-gram [ eh]
Adding  N-gram [ hi]
Exception in thread "Thread-2" Adding  N-gram [ ih]
Adding  N-gram [ hi]
Adding  N-gram [ ay]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ie.gmit.sw.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: The NullPointerException is unrelated to the question you ask. It occurs because you have set Consumer.dbFile to null and then try to use it like it refers to a instance.

Comment: If i use dbFile.add(t); in my FileParser() class it adds the elements to map in my DataBase()  class

Comment: @mark There is no problem in saving the reference of an object in different locations, like your `BlockingQueue` and your `Map`. Please [edit] your question to include the actual problem you have.